# Add members from card details?

Tags: trello

I made a board to archive our trello cards, the problem is when I moved the lists of cards to the new board, it deleted the other members except me.
They are still mentionned being added to the card in the card details before I moved the lists to the new board.

I have tried making a board button to add them back but I can't access the cards details in Butler

Is there a way to do this and save me a lot of time and pain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people to be added to a card in trello, they first need to be a members of the board.
Can you confirm they are members of your new archive board?